# How can a public ASP web form and web service be hosted to access a local, internal, SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, forms, web-services, iis

I am creating an ASP web form hosted on a public Microsoft web host. I need it to access a SQL database located locally on our internal network. I have developed a web service that talks to the ASP web form, but I don’t know where the web service should be located and how to get the data from the ASP web form to the local SQL database on our network.

So it's really two questions:

1. Where should the web service be located? On the public Microsoft host or on the internal network host?
2. How would the web service get the information from the public ASP web form to the internal SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding the first question:**

I guess you mean that the web server contacts the web service, not the other way around.

My guess would be to have the service at your company network if you want to contact the database for more than one application.

If there is no need for the database over there, i would place the service, database and web server to the cloud you are using, since this is better for availability and performance.

**Regarding the second question:**

You could look into some basic database interaction code like in ADO.NET or Entity Framework. Use MSDN as a starting point.

Comment: No problem. Is this answer was helpful or not, please don't forget to vote: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote yet, but I have marked your answer as the most helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Azure, when you say MS web host? Azure (and other cloud services) allow you to create a site to site virtual network e.g on Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/

If not Azure, but something like Rackspace they often have similar functionality: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/configure-a-site-to-site-vpn-using-the-vyatta-network-appliance

With this network configured, you could connect securely to your local SQL instance.

Latency and line speed will limit performance, obviously. You would need to experiment. Ultimately it would probably be better as suggested in the other answer to host your database in the cloud too.